# SwiftUI View of Transactions like GreenBooks

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment

I want to make a view of transactions that look like this.

[image]

The payee is supposed to go to the top left. Then the category under the payee.

Then, to the far right goes the amount spent at the top and the date at the bottom.

However, the best I've managed to get is this. There's no issue with the text but the alignment is off.

[image]

Here is my current code for the view:

```
struct TransactionView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List(transactions) {transaction in

      HStack {
          VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(transaction.lm_payee).font(.headline)
            Text(String(transaction.lm_category_id)).font(.subheadline)
          }

          VStack {
            Text(String(transaction.lm_amount)).font(.headline)
            Text(String(transaction.lm_date)).font(.subheadline)
          }.padding(.leading)
      }.padding(.horizontal).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

    }.navigationBarTitle("Transactions")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
struct TransactionView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List(transactions) {transaction in

      HStack {
          VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(transaction.lm_payee).font(.headline)
            Text(String(transaction.lm_category_id)).font(.subheadline)
          }

          Spacer()

          VStack {
            Text(String(transaction.lm_amount)).font(.headline)
            Text(String(transaction.lm_date)).font(.subheadline)
          }.padding(.leading)
      }.padding(.horizontal).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

    }.navigationBarTitle("Transactions")
  }
}
```

I injected Spacer() between the two VStacks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple layout, it can possibly be accomplished with something along the lines of this.

[image: swiftui]

```swift
struct ListItem: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Doordash*frutta Bowls + 1650681")
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    Text("Uncategorized")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text(Double(-18.38).currency)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    Text(Date(), style: .relative)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ListItem()
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

extension Double {
    var currency: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        return formatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
    }
}
```